# How to overwrite /modules/user/user.module text?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I am trying to override the text outputted on the user login block:

"A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail."

I have copied "/modules/user/user.module" to my site's theme folder and overwritten the text in question however I'm not seeing the change.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Thank you,

Andrew

Comment: I think you new to drupal. Are you looking for change email text or get password on mail or subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just this one string you want to change have a look at the String overrides section in `settings.php`:

> To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling the
>   Locale module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows
>   you to change a small number of your site's default English language
>   interface strings.

The string you'll need to replace is `'A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to change this text

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_profile_form':
    case 'user_register_form':
      $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('My text');
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Andrew. How do I implement this? Does it go into a template.php or functions.php file or do I need to write a custom module ie: http://websmiths.co/blog/very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter

Comment: hook_form_alter will work in template.php